# Is there any positive temperature from which superconductivity ceases?

Tags: temperature, superconductivity, critical-phenomena, low-temperature-physics

From what I understand about superconductivity, it is due to a coupling between Cooper pairs and phonons. At the absolute 0, there is no phonon, so I assume superconductivity cannot exist at that temperature. But for superconducting materials, is it possible to find a positive temperature below $T_c$ below which superconductivity ceases? If not, why not? If so, was it found for any material yet?

Comment: *"At the absolute 0, there is no phonon, so I assume superconductivity cannot exist at that temperature."* That is not correct. At absolute zero, there are no thermally activated phonons, but there are still phonons induced by the motion of the electrons themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on BCS theory, the phonon-mediated interaction is given by
$$V(\bf{k},\bf{q})\sim \frac{1}{(\epsilon_{\bf{k}}-\epsilon_{\bf{k}-\bf{q}})^2-(\hbar\omega_{\bf{q}})^2}$$
No matter how small $q$, and hence $\omega_{\bf{q}}$ is, we can always find $\bf{k}$ near the Fermi surface to make the energy difference as small as we like, and in fact the difference can be made strictly 0. As a consequence, the interaction can be made effectively attractive, leading to the Cooper instability.